# Stop div element from bouncing on resize

Tags: html, angular, typescript, tailwind-css

I am trying to make my calendar events resizable to adjust the event time, but when i adjust the height from the top, the bottom is bouncing around. I am using absolute positioning in the parent component to correctly place the events for the timeline, i also tried directly updating the positioning in the parent component but that had the same effect, I also tried updating the positioning, when `isResizing = true` then i changed the positioning `[style.position]='isResizing ? 'fixed': 'absolute'`. I also tried different approaches, like using cdkDrag directive and [interactjs](https://interactjs.io/) resizing.

When i resize the event from the bottom it works fine, this problem only occurse when the resize is started from the top.

this is the html code from my parent component

```
                  <user-calendar-event
                    class="absolute px-1"
                    [style.top]="event.top"
                    [style.bottom]="event.bottom"
                    [style.opacity]="eventOpacityChange(event)"
                    [style.z-index]="hoveredEvent === event.id ? 10 : 1"
                    [event]="event"
                    [color]="
                      event ? hoverColorChange(event.id, event.calendar_id) : ''
                    "
                    [weeklyEvent]="true"
                    (newHeight)="onEventResize($event, event)"
                    (resizingEvent)="isResizing = $event"
                    (click)="onClickedEvent($event)"
                    (mouseover)="hoveredEventId(event.id)"
                    (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave()"
                  >
                  </user-calendar-event>
```

and this is the code to resize the event:

```
      <div
        (mousedown)="startResizing($event, 'top')"
        class="absolute -top-xs left-1/2 w-full h-4 cursor-row-resize z-20"
      ></div>
      <div
        (mousedown)="startResizing($event, 'bottom')"
        class="absolute -bottom-xs left-1/2 w-full h-4 cursor-row-resize z-20"
      ></div>

  startResizing(event: MouseEvent, position: string) {
    this.resizingEvent.emit(true);

    const startY = event.clientY;
    const startHeight = this.container.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const heightPercentage = 100 / viewportHeight;
    const pixelsPerTimeSlot = 3 / heightPercentage;

    const mouseMove = (moveEvent: MouseEvent) => {
      const currentY = moveEvent.clientY;
      const diffY = currentY - startY;
      const timeSlotsMoved = Math.abs(diffY) / pixelsPerTimeSlot;
      let newHeight = 0;

      if (position === 'top'){
        this.container.nativeElement.style.transformOrigin = 'top';
        this.container.nativeElement.style.transform = `translateY(${diffY}px)`;
        newHeight =
          diffY > 0
            ? startHeight - Math.round(timeSlotsMoved) * pixelsPerTimeSlot
            : startHeight + Math.round(timeSlotsMoved) * pixelsPerTimeSlot;
      }
      else
        newHeight =
          diffY > 0
            ? startHeight + Math.round(timeSlotsMoved) * pixelsPerTimeSlot
            : startHeight - Math.round(timeSlotsMoved) * pixelsPerTimeSlot;

      this.container.nativeElement.style.height = `${Math.max(
        newHeight,
        20,
      )}px`;
    };

    const mouseUp = () => {
      const finalHeight = this.container.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
      const heightInPercent = finalHeight * heightPercentage;
      
      this.newHeight.emit(heightInPercent);
      this.container.nativeElement.style.transform = '';

      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
    };

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
  }
```

Comment: Are you using angular? If so and you think it's relevant to the question at all then consider adding it to the tags

Comment: Is this a schedular from a library, or one you've written yourself? [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs%2Fmintplayer-ng-bootstrap%2Fscheduler%2Fsrc) another, working schedular component with a [demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/scheduler)

Comment: @Pieterjan no i am trying not to use many 3rd party npm packages, so i am currently not using any schedular of some sort, the code i have provided is the code i have written myself